# Geometry nodes: I have a curve with multiple intersections. Is there a way to split each 'arm' into a separate closed object?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

[image]

I have multiple curves that look similar to this. With random T or + intersections. Is there a way to split each of them into a separate closed curve or mesh using geometry nodes? I basically want to be able to split them later, extrude and move them around etc. Kind of like having tetris blocks.

Comment: Arbitrary red cuts... what are the rules in your opinion?

Comment: Ideally the T or + shaped intersections. But if that's too complex I guess all areas where there is a > than 30° angle?